# How to prevent a scheduled GitHub workflow from executing on a fork?

Tags: github

I have set up a [GitHub workflow to send a POST request every 3 hours](https://ericjinks.com/blog/2019/netlify-scheduled-build/). What happens when somebody forks my repository on GitHub? Now there would be two repositories with the same workflow. Is GitHub going to send 2 requests every 3 hours? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, this should not disturb your scheduled build.

Even though they have your workflow file, they will not have access key to send the request if you have maintained the key outside the workflow file.

Some references:

https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Stop-github-actions-running-on-a-fork/td-p/51499

https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Protecting-github-workflows/td-p/30290

https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/disabling-or-limiting-github-actions-for-a-repository

https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo

Comment: I did not realize "GitHub secrets" is a thing which exists, and that the POST URL could be placed inside a secret. Thanks!